# Why can't assign the generic variables in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

Why can't assign the generic variables in Dart?

```
void test<T1 extends num, T2 extends String>(T2 arg) {
    //    ↓ A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T1'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'T1'.
    T1 t = 0;

    //     ↓↓↓↓ A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T2'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'T2'.
    arg = 'Test';
}
```

Comment: Those assignments aren't safe.  You can't assign a base type (in this case, `num` or `String`) where a more specific (i.e., narrower) type is expected.  For example, `T1` could be a `double`, which would satisfy `extends num`, but you cannot directly assign an `int` to a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

An example might help to understand generic

```
print(add(10.5, 20));
T add<T extends num>(T a, T b) => a + b as T;
```